# Inclusion $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is a bijection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory

How to prove that the inclusion $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Q}$ is both a monomorphism and an epimorphism in the category of unital commutative rings?

Comment: what is meant by "bijic"?

Comment: bijic is short for bijective

Comment: In other words how to prove the inclusion Z->Q is both monomorphism and epimorphism.

Comment: since $\mathbb{Q}$ and $\mathbb{Z}$ are both countable there definitely exists a bijection between them. But you can't say that the inclusion is bijective as $\mathbb{Z}$ is properly contained in $\mathbb{Q}$

Comment: That is a very nonstandard use of "bijective." A morphism which is both a monomorphism and an epimorphism is sometimes called a bimorphism (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/bimorphism), although personally I think this is a terrible term. I sometimes use the term "fake isomorphism."

Comment: @JAK the inclusion map is definitely a morphism of rings and is  injective but I don't see why it should be surjective.

Comment: @Rise I know but I am supposed to prove that. :(

Comment: @JAK wouldn't the inclusion just be $n\mapsto n$? You can't get $\frac{1}{2}$ from that.

Comment: There is a massive gap between title and question....

Comment: @Mathmo123 Although it is clear that must be the intended question, part of the problem may be that the OP does not realise the difference between the two. You should not make such a drastic edit.

Comment: @ZhenLin The edit was based on the OP's comment above "In other words how to prove the inclusion Z->Q is both monomorphism and epimorphism". I think it's fair to assume from the original wording that the OP understands this is not a bijection of sets, and that this was a confusion of terms rather than a confusion of concepts. As the question stood, it was receiving answers that would not have been helpful to the OP.

Comment: I am given to understand that there are some old textbooks that _define_ epimorphism to be surjective homomorphism. At any rate, this is obviously the point of contention.

Answer (score 2):

It is certainly not bijective. Showing it is a monomorphism is trivial (why?) Showing it is an epimorphism is almost as easy; think about two functions $f,g: \mathbb{Q} \to R$ that disagree on some value. Can it be that $f \circ i = g \circ i$?

Answer (score 1):

Even though the cardinality of $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ are same, its not a bijection (its an embedding but not a surjection). $\frac{1}{2}$ is not in the image set.